# Making a UILabel fit nicely into a Collection View Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, label

I have collection view cells with equal width and height in a flow layout. They contain a single UILabel, which `numberOfLines` property is set to `0`. The constraints of the label are:

[image]

The cell is made circular:

```
 cell.layer.cornerRadius = cell.frame.width / 2
 cell.clipsToBounds = true
```

I increase the size of each cell based on the label's text size. However, it's width and height can't be greater than `150`. Here is how I determine the size of each cell:

```
private func estimatedFrameForText(text: String) -> CGRect {
    let size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 1000)
    let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(.usesLineFragmentOrigin)

    return NSString(string: text).boundingRect(with: size, options: options, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)], context: nil)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {


    let hashLabelText = textArray[indexPath.item]
    let textSize = estimatedFrameForText(text: hashLabelText)


    let width = min(150, textSize.width + 20)
    let height = width

    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
}
```

With this I get the following result (I'm showing the part where the cells' width and height are equal to `150`).:

[image]

As you can see, when the cell hits its maximum possible size and the text of the labels continues to increase, at some point, the text gets off the visible part of the cells. I understand why this happens (the layout debugger shows this clearly), however I can't find a solution to the problem, yet.

What I want is that the edges of the label remain visible no matter what is the size of the cell. The text's tail can be truncated if the cell reaches its maximum size, but the text continues to increase.

I've tried to increase the space between the label and the bounds of the cells but that affects how the text looks in the smallest cells. I've also tried to change the minimum font scale of the label, but again, without a success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `UIEdgeInsets` for this, Create a class for UILabel:

```
import UIKit

class UILabelDraw: UILabel {
    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        let insets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10.0, left: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, right: 10.0)
        super.drawText(in: UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets))
    }
}
```

Use this class as a Label class like below:

[image]

> Output of `UIEdgeInsets` is below:

[image]

Comment: Welcome, My pleasure to help you.